# Special taxes in cart has to be shown separately

Tags: checkout, cart, tax, billing, germany

I have a problem with the german tax law.
In german are two standard tax classes.
The normal tax class of 19% for all and the special tax class of 7% for food....

And there is a very special tax class for "forest work" with 10.7% (Sorry. Don´t know the right translation)

My Customer sells small trees and special plants. 
I have to build his shop and my first big problem is this "tree tax".

In the cart, the checkout and the bill this tax has to be shown separately.
The normal magento system only shows the total tax of all.

It should looks like this.

1x Produkt 1: 10.00€ (19%)
1x Produkt 2: 10.00€ (10.7%)
+++
Subtotal: 20.00€
Tax(19%): 1.90€
Tax(10.7%): 1.07€
Shipping: 6.90€
Shipping-Tax(19%): 1.31€

Total(incl. tax): 26.90€
Total(excl. tax): 22,62€
Tax total: 4.28€

I have no problems with subtotal,shipping,totals and tax totals, but i can´t find a solution for Tax(19%) and Tax(10.7%).

Where can ich find this values?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Configuration** > **General**.
**Sales** tab > **Tax**

**Display Full Tax Summary – Yes**.

Then you should be able to click the tax i.e. on cart totals table and it should expand into two rows with tax amount for each rate. At least it works in Magento 1.8.1.0 with default theme (just checked).

Comment: On a 1.9 magento it doesn't work, it shows me the sum of both taxes, how can I display an amount separately for each tax? Thanks

Comment: Just checked on a sample data installation - it does. Screenshot prove: http://imgur.com/Yx8cBRV Bear in mind that theme customization might be done poorly.

Comment: Try applying 2 taxes, here's the question I've posted yesterday with screens: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155135/tax-rate-summary-breakdown-in-cart