# Tax values are displaying Differently in Order view page & Invoice view page

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, tax, tax-class

In **System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Orders, Invoices, Credit Memos Display** Settings , if we set **Display Full Tax Summary** to **Yes** , than its Display Tax summary correctly in **Invoice Page**, but not in **Order view pag**e.

can anyone give me an idea where i need to debug ?

[image]

Invoice page :

[image]

order view page :

[image]

**Edit**

If we set **Different priority** for SGST and CGST , than it will work in order view page, but when we set **same Priority** than it will not work in order view page.

[image]

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/totals - Tax.phtml

```
<?php
/** @var $_source Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice */
$_source = $this->getSource();
$_order = $this->getOrder();
$_fullInfo = $this->getFullTaxInfo();
$_weees = $this->helper('tax')->getAllWeee($_order);
global $taxIter;
$taxIter++;
?>

<?php if ($this->displayFullSummary()): ?>
    <?php $isTop = 1; ?>
    <?php if (isset($_fullInfo[0]['rates'])): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_fullInfo as $info): ?>
            <?php if (isset($info['hidden']) && $info['hidden']) continue; ?>
            <?php
            $percent = $info['percent'];
            $amount = $info['amount'];
            $baseAmount = $info['base_amount'];
            $rates = $info['rates'];
            $isFirst = 1;
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($rates as $rate): ?>
                <tr class="summary-details<?php if ($isTop): echo ' summary-details-first'; endif; ?>"
                    style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (!is_null($rate['percent'])): ?>
                        <td class="label"><?php echo $rate['title']; ?> (<?php echo (float)$rate['percent']; ?>%)<br/>
                        </td>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <td class="label"><?php echo $rate['title']; ?><br/></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($isFirst): ?>
                        <td rowspan="<?php echo count($rates); ?>"><?php echo $this->displayAmount($amount, $baseAmount); ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $isFirst = 0;
                $isTop = 0;
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php foreach ($_fullInfo as $info): ?>
            <?php
            $percent = $info['percent'];
            $amount = $info['tax_amount'];
            $baseAmount = $info['base_tax_amount'];
            $isFirst = 1;
            ?>

            <tr class="summary-details<?php if ($isTop): echo ' summary-details-first'; endif; ?>"
                style="display:none;">
                <?php if (!is_null($info['percent'])): ?>
                    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($info['title']); ?>
                        (<?php echo (float)$info['percent']; ?>%)<br/></td>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($info['title']); ?><br/></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td><?php echo $this->displayAmount($amount, $baseAmount); ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $isFirst = 0;
            $isTop = 0;
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php foreach ($_weees as $weeeTitle => $weeeAmount): ?>
        <tr class="summary-details-<?php echo $taxIter; ?> summary-details<?php if ($isTop): echo ' summary-details-first'; endif; ?>"
            style="display:none;">
            <td class="a-right" colspan="1">
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($weeeTitle); ?>
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td class="a-right" rowspan="1">
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($weeeAmount); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->displayFullSummary() && ($_fullInfo || $_weees)): ?>
<tr class="summary-total" onclick="expandDetails(this, '.summary-details')">
    <?php else: ?>
<tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="label">
        <div class="summary-collapse">
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayFullSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Tax') ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->displayAmount($_source->getTaxAmount(), $_source->getBaseTaxAmount()); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: may i know how you can differentiate CGST, SGST and IGST

Comment: @JeevaRathinam what our finance team said is if within state, than go for `CGST & SGST` and if outside the state, than it will be `IGST`...... and we followed this [link](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-gst-tax-rule-magento/) to achieve what `Mr. Narendara modi ji said`.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     default_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
/** @var $this Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Totals_Tax */
?>
<?php
/** @var $_source Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice */
$_source = $this->getSource();
$_order = $this->getOrder();
$_fullInfo = $this->getFullTaxInfo();
$_weees = $this->helper('tax')->getAllWeee($_order);
global $taxIter;
$taxIter++;
?>

<?php if ($this->displayFullSummary()): ?>
    <?php $isTop = 1; ?>
    <?php if (isset($_fullInfo[0]['rates'])): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_fullInfo as $info): ?>
            <?php if (isset($info['hidden']) && $info['hidden']) continue; ?>
            <?php
            $percent = $info['percent'];
            $amount = $info['amount'];
            $baseAmount = $info['base_amount'];
            $rates = $info['rates'];
            $isFirst = 1;
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($rates as $rate): ?>
                <tr class="summary-details<?php if ($isTop): echo ' summary-details-first'; endif; ?>"
                    style="display:none;">
                    <?php if (!is_null($rate['percent'])): ?>
                        <td class="label"><?php echo $rate['title']; ?> (<?php echo (float)$rate['percent']; ?>%)<br/>
                        </td>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <td class="label"><?php echo $rate['title']; ?><br/></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($isFirst): ?>
                        <td rowspan="<?php echo count($rates); ?>"><?php echo $this->displayAmount($amount, $baseAmount); ?></td>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
                $isFirst = 0;
                $isTop = 0;
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php foreach ($_fullInfo as $info): ?>
            <?php
           $percent = $info['percent'];
            $amount = $info['tax_amount'];
            $baseAmount = $info['base_tax_amount'];
            $isFirst = 1;

            ?>

            <tr class="summary-details<?php if ($isTop): echo ' summary-details-first'; endif; ?>"
                style="display:none;">
                <?php if (!is_null($info['percent'])): ?>
                    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($info['title']); ?>
                        (<?php echo (float)$info['percent']; ?>%)<br/></td>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <td class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($info['title']); ?><br/></td>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td><?php //echo $this->displayAmount($amount, $baseAmount); ?> 
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice(($_order->getBaseSubtotal()*$info['percent'])/100 ); //print_r($_order->getData());?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $isFirst = 0;
            $isTop = 0;
            ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php foreach ($_weees as $weeeTitle => $weeeAmount): ?>
        <tr class="summary-details-<?php echo $taxIter; ?> summary-details<?php if ($isTop): echo ' summary-details-first'; endif; ?>"
            style="display:none;">
            <td class="a-right" colspan="1">
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($weeeTitle); ?>
                <br/>
            </td>
            <td class="a-right" rowspan="1">
                <?php echo $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($weeeAmount); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($this->displayFullSummary() && ($_fullInfo || $_weees)): ?>
<tr class="summary-total" onclick="expandDetails(this, '.summary-details')">
    <?php else: ?>
<tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <td class="label">
        <div class="summary-collapse">
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayFullSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Tax') ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->displayAmount($_source->getTaxAmount(), $_source->getBaseTaxAmount()); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: is there an explanation for this solution? what does this do?